# "Advanced English Studies "

Tags: grammatical-number

I typed in study instead of studies and is marked wrong. Is there a reason to use the plural form?[image]

Comment: Titles of academic courses generally use 'studies' as they encompass a wide range of knowledge within that subject.  Otherwise, you could call it The Study of Advanced English, but that is a bit too verbose for a snappy title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong as far as it is not traditionnal to say "study" in that context. You will rather say for instance "In his study of English he had little success" and avoid "…his studies …" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+his+studies+of%2Cin+his+study+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20his%20studies%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20his%20study%20of%3B%2Cc0)); here again we are confronted to mere usage, tradition if you prefer, but that is important; in a title the plural is the norm; otherwise, that is from a logical point of view, there is nothing wrong if you use the singular.

Here "studies" is in the plural because it is taken as the name of a subject rather than simply as the action of studying.

Answer (score 1):

The box is asking for the title of the course. If the title is "Advanced English Studies" then that is what you should write.